# R markdown in loops - plotly and dygraph don't work

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, dygraphs, r-plotly

R markdown in loops - plotly and dygraph don't work

Stack Overflow gave me `results='asis'` and `cat('\n')` but they didn't help.

I'd like a solution, but also an explanation of why it doesn't work for plotly and dygraph but does for e.g. ggplot.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dygraphs)
library(plotly)
```
```{r testing plotly, results='asis'}
for (n in 1:3){
  p <- plot_ly(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)+n, mode = 'lines', type="scatter")
  p
  cat('\n')
}
```

```{r testing dygraph, results='asis'}
d=data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10))
for (n in 1:3){
  p <- dygraph(d)
  p
  cat('\n')
}
```
````

Comment: You may also see https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/983 and https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1069.

Comment: Hi Yihui - in an effort to provide a minimum example, I left out the fact that my true use case would require two inputs to a function and with my newbie R-skills I can't figure out how to do that with lapply. Suggestions?